# Three phase system represented as a vector

Tags: three-phase

In multiple locations I've been seeing the following:

"Any three phase system can be defined by the vector As:

\$ A_s = \frac{2}{3}[Ax(t) + (c)Ay(t) + (c^2)Az(t)]\$

Where \$ c=e^{j\frac{2\pi}{3}} \$"

I understand this is showing the resultant of three sinusoids 120 degrees apart (from the c coefficient) but I cannot for the life of me remember where the \$ \frac{2}{3} \$ coefficient is coming from. Can anyone explain where this \$ \frac{2}{3} \$ coefficient is from? I assume its a byproduct of vector addition maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for. [image]

Definitely wasn't as simple as I thought it was.